# Session share in php

Tags: php

Currently I am doing a project which runs both on Zend Framework (For Web site) and phone gap (For Mobile). I need to use the same code for website and web service for mobile.

Now I am facing the below mentioned issue,

The web service which I am calling from phone gap is to create the session and the session was created successfully. Now i am calling the another web service to get the user details based on session id. But the details are not displaying, because the session id is giving empty.  So can you please suggest how can i proceed with this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Session is not shareable. Try saving session id to database (or file) and than read it from server side.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please give more information about how sessions are managed?

From the look of it, you might need to to use both $_SESSION and potentially an implementation of the SessionClassHandler interface to store sessions in a central database.

Also you might have issues with cookies, so you might need to pass the session id via URL. But this is very insecure so if this is the case, make sure that you at least use https or put oher mecanisms in place.

I hope this helps

Comment: I am using the zend framework for website and phone gap for mobile application. At a first time, I am sending the values for login purpose and session was created successfully, giving the response also. Now i am calling the web service to get profile details, it give the response as empty, because there is no session id at this moment. So i want to get the profile details

Comment: OK well it looks like you need to read on the fundamentals of sessions.. my answer above explains the high level steps you would need to perform but its hard to help you more than this.